# Multiple checkbox selected in a loop PHP

Tags: php, html, loops, checkbox

I have a loop that offers several checkboxes to the user:

```
<?php
while($personInfo = $selectPerson->fetch())
{
?>

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxValue[]" id="checkBoxValue" value="<?= $personInfo['title'] ?>"> <?= $personInfo['title'] ?>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    </label> | 
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="improper" id="improper" value="0"> Improper
    </label>
    <hr>

<?php
}
?>
```

The thing is that I manage to recover each checkbox selected by the user with:

```
foreach($_POST['checkBoxValue'] as $selected)
{
    echo $selected;
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

But I do not see how I can know if for each checkbox selected, the checkbox "Improper" is also selected.

Comment: Same way as you did the `checkBoxValue` one `name="improper[]"`

Comment: along with @DarkBee ans.make sure your id is unique. this is not in your case.

Comment: @DarkBee Hmmm except if checkboxes are not checked they are not returned to the PHP. So if the first checkbox `checkboxValue` is checked and second `improper` is checked they will both be returned in the `[0]`'th occurance leading to MAJOR confusion and errors

Comment: Well it's actual better to indicate which checkbox belongs with which person by changing it up `<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxValue[<?= $personInfo['id'] ?>]" id="checkBoxValue_<?= $personInfo['id'] ?>">` - Then you just can use an `isset` check combined with the id of the person

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the ID of the person..

Comment: I know the ID but I don't really understand "use an isset check combined with the id of the person"

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['checkBoxValue'][$personInfo['id']])) { ... }` and `if (isset($_POST['improper'][$personInfo['id']])) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="stackOverflow">
<?php
$personInfo = [['id' => 2,  'title' => "Bernard"], [ 'id' => 3, 'title' => "Marc"]];
foreach ($personInfo as $info) {
    ?>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxValue[<?php echo $info["id"] ?>]" id="checkBoxValue<?php echo $info["id"]; ?>" value="<?= $info['title'] ?>"
            <?php if (isset($_POST['checkBoxValue'][$info["id"]])) { ?>
                checked
            <?php } ?>
        >
        <?= $info['title'] ?>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label> | <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="improper[<?php echo $info["id"] ?>]" id="improper_<?php echo $info["id"]; ?> "
            <?php if (isset($_POST['improper'][$info["id"]]) && "on" === $_POST['improper'][$info["id"]]) { ?>
                checked
            <?php } ?>
        >
        Improper
    </label>
    <hr>
    <?php
}
?>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="btn_validation" value="submit">
```